# gulpjs - merge multiple files to make one gulpfile

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am loving `gulpjs`, but am having an issue where my `gulpfile.js` is just getting really, really big.

I have searched pretty extensively and am having difficulty finding resources related to this, but is it possible to split a `gulpfile.js` up into multiple smaller `js` files just for organization?

Comment: a-ha-ha, well, you can use grunt to compule your gulpfile.js and then run it )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it this way (I use coffeescript, but the theory is sound), similar to the above:

```
tasks = fs.readdirSync './gulp/tasks'
tasks.forEach (task)->
  require "./tasks/#{task}" if task.indexOf('coffee') >= 0
```

All it does is read the task folder and require all the files in it as long as they're .coffee files (which isn't 100% kosher, but it does avoid hidden dotfiles).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it to manage your tasks. For example if you have this file organization:

```
gulpfile.js
-- tasks
---- test.js
---- dev.js
```

You have to install de require-div module:

```
npm install require-dir --save-dev
```

And, finally, you add this code to your gulpfile

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
var dir = requireDir('./tasks');
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.